# Send excel file data to Node.js server and parse it into json

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, server-side

I am relatively new to node.js and not so great at javascript. But what I am trying to do is send a .xlsx file to node.js, and then convert it to json. but my req.body is always {}. My process is, I want to have the user select an excel file, then click submit on their form field, and then have the server side turn that excel file into json.

My code:
HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
                            <form name="myForm" action="sendFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input id="fileName" name="fileName" type="file"  class="validate" >
                                <input type="submit">
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

And my server code:

```
app.post("/sendFile", function(req, res){
    console.log("--------------in batch create user--------------");
    console.log("body is: "+ req.body);
    console.log(req.body.fileName);  // is undefined
    console.log(req.body); //is {}

    //I tried this as a second option but this didnt work either....

    // var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    // form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    //     console.log(files);
    //     console.log(fields);
    //     console.log(files.filetoupload);
    //     var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
    //
    //     convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;
    //     convertExcel(oldpath, null, null, function(err, data){
    //         console.log("----in convert excell ---------");
    //         console.log("data for excel is: "+data);
    //
    //     });
    // });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express you need a middleware to parse the request body and 
the multer library to process the multipart/form-data content. [Link for the library here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Here follow a short example of your scenario:

Obs: The part of the conversion of Excel to Json you can use the library of your question or [node-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-excel-to-json).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-field col s6">
                            <form name="myForm" action="/sendFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input id="fileName" name="fileName" type="file"  class="validate" >
                                <input type="submit">
                            </form>
                        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer();

var app = express();

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//form-urlencoded

// for parsing multipart/form-data
//app.use(upload.array());

//static folder
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
        //console.log(data);
        res.write(data)
    });
});

app.post("/sendFile",  upload.single('fileName'), function(req, res){

    //text fields
    console.log(req.body);

    //file contents
    console.log(req.file);


    // process
    var response = 'Do something';
    res.json(response);

});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
});
```